# Data analysis: Get corresponding values to another column

Tags: matlab, analysis

I'm doing data analysis in **Matlab**, and I have two columns. I'm using find(column1>0) to find the positive values of the first column in a data set. Now, I want to plot (column1,column2), but it is of course not possible, as the size is not the same. The question:

How do I get the corresponding values in column2 for the positive values in column1? Like, if row 17 and row 42 have a positive value in column1, how do I find the value of row 17 and row 42 in column2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for what you are doing is [indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html).  You *can* use `find`, which generates linear indices, but you shouldn't in this case.  Logical indexing is more appropriate.

```
index = column1 > 0; #% creates a logical index with true where the  
#% condition is satisfied and false otherwise.

values1 = column1(index);
values2 = column2(index);
#% values1 and values2 will be the same size, since they were indexed the same

plot(values1,values2); #% or however you want to do it.
```